# Generate csv data

Tags: sql, database, excel, csv

I am trying to generate test data regarding 22 players in 75 different training sessions. I have a player table whit the playerId (1,2,3..22) and a training session table with sessionId (1,2,3..75). How can I generate a relational table with test data between these tables with composite keys? Each player can only participate once in each session, and each players shouldn't participate in every training session. CSV is the desired output format. I have tried formulas in excel and online tools like Mackaroo.

The CSV output data could look like this:

```
ExerciseId,PlayerId
1,2
1,4
1,6
2,2
2,4
2,6
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  I assume the generation of a CSV file is not the real issue; matching players and sessions is.

Comment: I am only trying to generate some data, I know how to create the table and insert the data in my SQL Server. I just want to create some sample data.